# How to call JS function on AngularJS view change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to call couple of JavaScript functions (placeholder fallback etc) on AngularJS view change. How can I achieve this globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for the route change success event and call the functions inside the callback:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(next, current) { 
   // call your functions here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the following $scope.on you can also add a custom function using ng-init when the controller is called (new view state).

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="home-services" ng-init="init()"> 
  --- Code ---
</div>
```

ANGULARJS:

```
angular.module('home').controller('home-services', function($scope){
  $scope.init = function(){

  ---- Your Javascript ----

  };
});
```